# What's this green crispy vegetable or edible seaweed?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

[image]

My grandparents saw, but didn't take, these online images at Chiu Chow Garden restauarant in Central, Hong Kong. They can't remember which website: perhaps OpenRice? What's the scientific name for the green?

Sources: [Left](https://fastly.4sqi.net/img/general/600x600/15770739_wa4Rx2ZmFyaKtDFAqh7OZpE4QEvKf4qIAz4IxtjimqA.jpg), [Right](https://fastly.4sqi.net/img/general/600x600/15770739_QV6ft3HpyIrcDSPUewbV7nG_nDBw-8VZEhQp5TXkwXM.jpg) picture.

Answer (score 3):

##### I disagree with [the other answer on Nov 13 2019](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/103443). This looks like [**deep fried basil**](https://tastyasia.net/2013/01/27/chiu-chow-chicken-with-fried-basil/).

[image]

Comment: yes.  with the purple ribs on the leaves, it looks like Thai basil, fried

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [qúndài cài (裙带菜)/Wakame/sea mustard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakame).
[image]